# How special is the global variable _G?

Tags: lua, global-variables, environment, lua-table

Excerpt from [Lua 5.3 manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-_G):

> #### _G
>
> A global variable (not a function) that holds the global environment (see §2.2). Lua itself does not use this variable; changing its value does not affect any environment, nor vice versa.

Relevant part from §2.2

> […] every chunk is compiled in the scope of an external local variable named `_ENV`, so `_ENV` itself is never a free name in a chunk.
>
> […]
>
> Any table used as the value of `_ENV` is called an environment.
>
> Lua keeps a distinguished environment called the global environment. This value is kept at a special index in the C registry. In Lua, the global variable `_G` is initialized with this same value. (`_G` is never used internally.)
>
> When Lua loads a chunk, the default value for its `_ENV` upvalue is the global environment. Therefore, by default, free names in Lua code refer to entries in the global environment

I understand that for every chunk loaded, since `_ENV` would be the first upvalue, it is *pointed to* the global environment table, pointed by `_G` by `load`.

```
> =_G, _ENV
table: 006d1bd8 table: 006d1bd8
```

confirms that both point to the same table.  The manual states, rather reassures multiple times, that `_ENV` and `_G` are just regular names with no hidden meaning and that Lua itself doesn't use it internally.  I tried this chunk below:

```
local a = { }
local b = a      -- since tables are objects, both refer to the same table object
print(a, b)      -- same address printed twice
a = { }          -- point one of them to a newly constructed table
print(a, b)      -- new, old table addresses printed
```

Now doing the same with `_G` and `_ENV`:

```
local g = _G          -- make an additional reference
print(g, _G, _ENV)    -- prints same address thrice
local p = print       -- backup print for later use
_ENV = { }            -- point _ENV to a new table/environment
p(g, _G, _ENV)        -- old, nil, new

table: 00ce1be0    table: 00ce1be0    table: 00ce1be0
table: 00ce1be0    nil                table: 00ce96e0
```

If `_G` is an ordinary global, why is it becoming `nil` here?  If reference counting is done, `_G`, was still holding a reference at the time `_ENV` released it.  Like `b` above, it too should be holding on to the old table, no?

However, for the below chunk, `_G` is unchanged / preserved!

```
_ENV = { _G = _G }
_G.print(_G, _ENV, _ENV._G)   -- old, new, old
```

But here it is killed:

```
_ENV = { g = _G }
_ENV.g.print(_ENV, _ENV.g, _G)    -- new, old, nil
```

Another case where it is preserved:

```
print(_G, _ENV)                       -- print same address twice
local newgt = {}                      -- create new environment
setmetatable(newgt, {__index = _G})   -- set metatable with _G as __index metamethod
_ENV = newgt                          -- point _ENV to newgt
print(_G, newgt, _ENV)                -- old, new, new
```

With so many variations in the behaviour of `_G`, the original reassurance given by the manual seems shaky.  What am I missing here?

Comment: All global variables are silently prepended by `_ENV.`  So, any occurrence of `_G` becomes `_ENV._G` before executing your script.

Comment: Excellent point! Despite knowing this fact, I failed to apply it in this situation. Could you please expand this comment into an answer? It completely solves the mystery.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### How special is the global variable `_G`?

It is special in three ways:

1. It uses a name [reserved for internal use by Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.1).
2. It is create by one of Lua's standard modules (in particular the
   ["base"](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lbaselib.c.html#luaopen_base) module). If you create a fresh `lua_State` without
   opening the "base" module, you won't have the `_G` variable. The
   standalone interpreter has all standard libraries already loaded,
   though.
3. Some third-party Lua modules use the global variable `_G`, and
   changing/removing it can break those modules.

### What's the point of `_G`?

Global variables in Lua are implemented using a normal table. Any
access to a variable that is not a `local` variable or an upvalue will
be redirected to this table. Local variables always take priority, so
if you have a global variable and a local variable with the same name,
you will always get the local one. And here `_G` comes into play: If
you want the global variable, you can say `_G.name` instead of `name`.
Assuming the name `_G` is not a local variable (it's reserved for Lua,
remember?!), this will always get you the value of the global variable
by using table indexing syntax and thus removing the ambiguity with
local variable names. In newer Lua versions (5.2+) you could also use
`_ENV.name` as an alternative, but `_G` predates those versions and is
kept for compatibility.

There are other cases where you want to get a hold of the globals
table, e.g. for setting a metatable. Lua allows you to customize the
behavior of tables (and other values) by setting a metatable using the
[`setmetatable`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-setmetatable) function, but you have to pass the table as a
parameter somehow. `_G` helps you do that.

If you have added a metatable to the globals table, in certain cases
you might want to circumvent the metamethods (`__index` and/or
`__newindex`) you've just installed. You can use [`rawget`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-rawget) and
[`rawset`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-rawset), but you need to pass the globals table as a parameter
as well.

Note that all the use-cases listed above only apply to Lua code *not*
C code. In C code you don't have named local variables, only stack
indices. So there is no ambiguity. And if you want a reference of the
globals table to pass to some function, you can use
[`lua_pushglobaltable`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pushglobaltable) (which [uses the registry](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lua.h.html#lua_pushglobaltable) instead of `_G`).
As a consequence, modules implemented in C don't use/need the `_G`
global variable. This applies to Lua's standard library (which is
implemented in C) as well. In fact, the references manual
[guarantees](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-_G), that `_G` (the variable, not the table) is not used
by Lua or its standard library.

### How does `_G` relate to `_ENV`?

Since version 5.0 Lua allows you to change the table used to look up
global variables on a per-(Lua-)function basis. In Lua 5.0 and 5.1
you used the [`setfenv`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setfenv) function for that (the globals table is
also called "function environment", hence the name `setfenv`). Lua 5.2
introduced a new approach using another special variable name `_ENV`.
`_ENV` is *not* a global variable though, Lua makes sure that every
chunk starts with an `_ENV` upvalue. The new approach works by letting
Lua translate any access to a non-local (and non-upvalue) variable
name `a` to `_ENV.a`. Whatever `_ENV` is at that point in the code
gets used to resolve global variables. This way is a lot safer because
you can't change the environment of code you didn't write yourself
(without using the debug library), and also more flexible because you
can change the environment for individual blocks of code by creating
`local` `_ENV` variables with limited scopes.

However, in any case you need a *default* environment that is used
before the programmer has a chance to set a custom one (or if the programmer
does not want to change it). On startup, Lua creates this default
environment (also called ["global environment"](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.2)) for you and stores
it in the [registry](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.5). This default environment is used as the
`_ENV` upvalue for all chunks unless you pass custom environments to
[`load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) or [`loadfile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-loadfile). `lua_pushglobaltable` also
retrieves this global environment directly from the registry, so
all C modules automatically use it for accessing global variables.

And *if* the standard "base" C module has been loaded, this
default "global environment" has a table field called `_G` that refers
back to the global environment.

### To sum it up:

- The global variable `_G` is actually `_ENV._G`.
- `_ENV` is not a global, but an upvalue or a local variable.
- The `_G` field of the default "global environment" points back to
  the global environment.
- `_G` and `_ENV` by default refer to the same table (said global
  environment).
- C code doesn't use either, but a field in the registry (which
  again points to the global environment *by definition*).
- You can replace `_G` (in the global environment) without breaking
  C modules or Lua itself (but you might break third-party Lua
  modules if not careful).
- You can replace `_ENV` whenever you want, because it only affects
  your own code (the current chunk/file at most).
- If you replace `_ENV`, you can decide for yourself whether `_G`
  (`_ENV._G`) will be available in the affected code, and what it
  points to.